# How can I set a global class in a rails app that any user can view and add to, regardless of authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a question and answer flow in a Rails app, and I need to be able to add new Questions to the Questions model, but have them available to any user of the app, not just the User who submitted the questions in the first place.

As it stands I've got the authentication built from the Hartl course - with one addition myself (the first user to sign in is an admin for an "Organization" and can add more users to that Organization). This means that any User who belongs_to that Organization  can see their related models and collaborate within the app, but a User from another Organization cannot see or interact with anything but their own data.

What I need now is the ability to add Questions to a Question model (Question belongs_to Organization) - but I'd like these to be Globally available (so the question set is built up over time, and Admin users can select questions that are important to their Users, but ignore other questions that are less relevant).

Is this possible in Rails? I presume I'd need to create a new class or something like that, but I don't really know what question to type into Google to get me on the right path.

Comment: you mean you want other users, who aren't from the same org. to be able to add questions?

Comment: how you built authentication ? with before_filter: in authentication controller ?

Comment: it would be very helpful if you update question with the respective codes you have in controller and model.

Comment: Abhinay - yes, I'd like the Questions model to live on its own, and be available to any User regardless of the Organization they belong_to. I'll add the code for authentication if you like, but I don't want to change that, I want to create a Class that can be accessed by any User.

Comment: you might not have to create a new class for this purpose. a small tweak can fix this issue, btw why do you think you need to create a Class anyway. i am just curious

Comment: I'm struggling to work out the right Data Model and method to implement the feature I want. I'm trying to think of the right question to ask here to get the answer I need to help - this is my latest thought process. I'd be interested in the tweak you suggest

Comment: In my understanding if you aren't checking for the condition whether this User belongs to a specific Org. there shouldn't be any issue. I feel you might have to explain a bit more using your code in order to get a proper fix.